# Adding image view constraint programmatically

Tags: swift, uikit, autolayout

The collectionview cell I created has a vertically limited space. I want to put an imageview and label on the vertical axis. But I want this image view to grow or shrink according to the screen size. The codes I wrote are as follows.

```
  private lazy var assetImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.tintColor = .secondaryLabel
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    imageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    return imageView
  }()

func configureViews() {
    contentView.addSameSizeConstrained(subView: containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(assetImageView)
    containerView.addSubview(assetTypeLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(assetCountLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      assetImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor,
        constant: AppLayoutGuidance.spacing
      ),
      assetImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: AppLayoutGuidance.spacingHalf),

      assetTypeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: assetImageView.trailingAnchor,
        constant: AppLayoutGuidance.spacingHalf
      ),
      assetTypeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor,
        constant: -AppLayoutGuidance.spacing
      ),
      assetTypeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: assetImageView.centerYAnchor),

      assetCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: assetImageView.leadingAnchor),
      assetCountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: assetTypeLabel.trailingAnchor),
      assetCountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: assetImageView.bottomAnchor,
        constant: AppLayoutGuidance.spacingHalf
      ),
      assetCountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor,
        constant: -AppLayoutGuidance.spacingHalf
      ),
    ])
  }
```

I can see the imageView getting bigger vertically but the image is not getting bigger to maintain the aspect ratio. Since it remains constant on the horizontal axis.

Simulator screen;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a constraint. You need configure your constraints on the image view to set the aspect ratio to match that the aspect ratio of the image being portrayed. The `multiplier` for this constraint, expressing the image view's width anchor in terms of its height anchor (or vice versa), will have to be set in your cell's configuration each time a new image is applied to the cell (because cells are reusable).

Comment: Isn't this enough?

    assetImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: assetImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

Comment: Well that would make the image view square. But that isn't what you want, as far as I can tell. In any case it's not in the code you showed in your question.

Comment: In fact, I want the picture to occupy as much horizontally as it occupies vertically. So I want it to be square.